# Issue With Large Array Sizes in CUDA

Tags: c, memory, cuda

I am familiarizing myself with CUDA by writing a dot product calculator. I wanted to test it with large array sizes to do a timing study to test two different ways of collecting the vector sum. However, when the size of the array is above 1024 I get errors. I am not so sure where the problem is coming from. The card is a GTX460M with 1.5GB of ram. I am using the card for display (this is a laptop). Aside that I am not sure where the issue could be coming from.

Here is the nvcc compile line:

```
nvcc D:\Research\CUDA\TestCode\test_dotProduct_1.cu --use_fast_math --gpu-architecture sm_13 --compiler-bindir="D:\Programming\VisualStudio\2010express\VC\bin" --machine 32 -o multi_dot.exe
```

I also seem to have trouble with compiling in 64 bit but that is another issue

Here is the output for an array of size 1024:
    HOST CALCULATION:     357389824.000000
    DEV PARA CALCULATION: 357389824.000000
    DEV SERI CALCULATION: 357389824.000000

Here is the output for an array of size 2048:
    HOST CALCULATION:     2861214720.000000
    DEV PARA CALCULATION: -1.#INF00
    DEV SERI CALCULATION: -1.#INF00

Here is my code:

```
 /*Code for a CUDA test project doing a basic dot product with doubles
*
*
*
*/
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <cuda.h>


 __global__ void GPU_parallelDotProduct(double *array_a, double *array_b, double     *array_c){
     array_c[threadIdx.x] = array_a[threadIdx.x] * array_b[threadIdx.x];
 }

 __global__ void GPU_parallelSumVector(double *vector, double *sum, int base){
    sum[threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x] = vector[blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x * base] +         vector[blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x * base + 1];
 }

__global__ void GPU_serialSumVector(double *vector, double *sum, int dim){
     for(int i = 0; i < dim; ++i){
         sum[0] += vector[i];
     }
}

__host__ void CPU_serialDot(double *first, double *second, double *dot, int dim){
     for(int i=0; i<dim; ++i){
         dot[0] += first[i] * second[i];
     }
 }

__host__ void CPU_serialSetupVector(double *vector, int dim, int incrSize, int start){
     for(int i=0; i<dim; ++i){
         vector[i] = start + i * incrSize;
     }
 }

 int main(){
     //define array size to be used
     //int i,j;
     const int VECTOR_LENGTH = 2048;
           int SUM_BASE      = 2;
           int SUM_ROUNDS    = VECTOR_LENGTH / SUM_BASE;
           int ELEMENT_SIZE  = sizeof(double);
           //   int currentSize   = VECTOR_LENGTH;
     //arrays for dot product
     //host
     double *array_a                  = (double*) malloc(VECTOR_LENGTH * ELEMENT_SIZE);
     double *array_b                  = (double*) malloc(VECTOR_LENGTH * ELEMENT_SIZE);
     double *dev_dot_product_parallel = (double*) malloc(VECTOR_LENGTH * ELEMENT_SIZE);
     double *dev_dot_product_serial   = (double*) malloc(VECTOR_LENGTH * ELEMENT_SIZE);
     double  host_dot_product         = 0.0;

     //fill with values
     CPU_serialSetupVector(array_a, VECTOR_LENGTH, 1, 0);
     CPU_serialSetupVector(array_b, VECTOR_LENGTH, 1, 0);
     CPU_serialDot(array_a, array_b, &host_dot_product, VECTOR_LENGTH);

     //device
     double *dev_array_a;
     double *dev_array_b;
     double *dev_array_c;
     double *dev_dot_serial;
     double *dev_dot_parallel;
     //allocate cuda memory
     cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_array_a,      ELEMENT_SIZE * VECTOR_LENGTH);
     cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_array_b,      ELEMENT_SIZE * VECTOR_LENGTH);
     cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_array_c,      ELEMENT_SIZE * VECTOR_LENGTH);
     cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_dot_parallel, ELEMENT_SIZE * VECTOR_LENGTH);
     cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_dot_serial,   ELEMENT_SIZE * VECTOR_LENGTH);


     //copy to from host to device
     cudaMemcpy(dev_array_a, array_a, ELEMENT_SIZE * VECTOR_LENGTH,     cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
     cudaMemcpy(dev_array_b, array_b, ELEMENT_SIZE * VECTOR_LENGTH,     cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
     cudaMemcpy(dev_dot_parallel, &dev_dot_product_parallel, ELEMENT_SIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
     cudaMemcpy(dev_dot_serial, &dev_dot_product_serial, ELEMENT_SIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

     //perform CUDA dot product
     GPU_parallelDotProduct<<<1, VECTOR_LENGTH>>>(dev_array_a, dev_array_b, dev_array_c);

     //condense a second vector in serial to compare speed up of tree condensing
     GPU_serialSumVector<<<1,1>>>(dev_array_c, dev_dot_serial, VECTOR_LENGTH);

     //condense vector (parallel)
     for(int i=SUM_ROUNDS; i>1; i/=SUM_BASE){
         GPU_parallelSumVector<<<1,i>>>(dev_array_c, dev_array_c, SUM_BASE);
     }
     GPU_parallelSumVector<<<1,1>>>(dev_array_c, dev_array_c, SUM_BASE);


     //get computed product back to the machine
     cudaMemcpy(dev_dot_product_parallel, dev_array_c, VECTOR_LENGTH * ELEMENT_SIZE,    cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
     cudaMemcpy(dev_dot_product_serial, dev_dot_serial, VECTOR_LENGTH * ELEMENT_SIZE, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

     FILE *output = fopen("test_dotProduct_1.txt", "w");
     fprintf(output, "HOST CALCULATION:     %f \n", host_dot_product);
     fprintf(output, "DEV PARA CALCULATION: %f \n", dev_dot_product_parallel[0]);
     fprintf(output, "DEV SERI CALCULATION: %f \n", dev_dot_product_serial[0]);
     /*
     fprintf(output, "VALUES OF DEV_ARRAY_C VEC: \n");
     for(int i=0; i<VECTOR_LENGTH; ++i){
        fprintf(output, "value %i is: %f \n", i, dev_dot_product_parallel[i]);
     }
     */
     free(array_a);
     free(array_b);
     //free(host_dot_product);
     cudaFree(dev_array_a);
     cudaFree(dev_array_b);
     cudaFree(dev_array_c);
     cudaFree(dev_dot_parallel);
     cudaFree(dev_dot_serial);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Please use some kind of error checking. This would be have been solved easily by cudaGetLastError() and cudaGetErrorString

Answer (score 6):

The maximum number of threads for a block for your card is 1024, which is why you are getting an error (for some older cards its 512). You either need to split up your blocks to use multiple dimensions (again limited to 1024 in a direction for x,y,z on your card) or use more than one block in your grid.